# To set a background image in .Net form

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to set an image to my .net form background using `BackgroundImage` property but it's not working. Please help me with it as soon.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add some detials to 'its not working'.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.BackGroundImage = New System.Drawing.Bitmap("c:\Users\user326613\Pups.bmp")
```